# Как поменять цвет на логотипе

Tags: html, css

Мне нужно сделать вот так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сейчас у меня вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}


header{
    margin: 33px auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo{
    margin-left: 10px;
}


header .menu_top li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

header .menu_top li a{
    display: block;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DataCloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <a href="/" class="logo"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menu_top">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PRICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="img/phone.png" alt="">
            <p>Contact now!<br>(012) 345-6789</p>

            <a href="#"><img src="img/search.png" alt=""></a>
    </header>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если логотип с прозрачностью, то классу `Logo` прописываем `background:#008ce6;`

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
}


header{
    margin: 33px auto;
    max-width: 1170px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.logo{
margin-left: 10px;
    background: #008ce6;
    position: relative;
    height: 64px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-content: center;
    width: 120px;
    justify-content: center;
}

.logo_img{width: 100px;}
header .menu_top li{
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 25px;
}

header .menu_top li a{
    display: block;
    color: #231f20;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>DataCloud</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <a href="/" class="logo"><img class="logo_img" src="https://downloader.disk.yandex.ru/preview/74f2a5a499a53aa622f811c6a75bb8496ea7e8b349570aa0f9dfe044e99d5d31/61e60b26/q948Otmt2QZx5WEmNotlaHYYX0Ort7DN-zqJMHnrI26Mwq6a84JyZlmgOqUwcoCshKcW0fBrOlytaDmRmPqksw%3D%3D?uid=0&filename=logo.png&disposition=inline&hash=&limit=0&content_type=image%2Fpng&owner_uid=0&tknv=v2&size=2048x2048" alt=""></a>
            <ul class="menu_top">
                <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="">ABOUT</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CLIENTS</a></li>
                <li><a href="">SERVICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">PRICES</a></li>
                <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <img src="img/phone.png" alt="">
            <p>Contact now!<br>(012) 345-6789</p>

            <a href="#"><img src="img/search.png" alt=""></a>
    </header>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: цвет будет только вокруг лого, а снизу и сверху будет белый фон

Comment: @Дима логотип выложите куда-нибудь

Comment: @Дима исправил ответ, добавил padding:10px;

Comment: padding 10px тоже не так как нужно, давайте я скину вам лого https://disk.yandex.ru/i/1JpykeJpvxoBRg

Comment: мне нужно, чтобы он выходил из header

Comment: @Дима Вопрос стоит как поменять цвет на логотипе. Непонятно кто должен за header выходить.

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/zCzquqCugRuwsA вот как у меня сейчас с  padding:10px;

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/RwZommWvlNCsww вот как мне нужно

Comment: @Дима минутку пожалуйста

Comment: @Дима исправил ответ, посмотрите как сейчас у вас

Comment: https://disk.yandex.ru/i/Dt-lB1O4oyZ5dQ сейчас у меня вот так

Comment: @Дима ну вроде так и надо было